# Wrong version of Firefox in Mozilla Addons (Linux Mint 18.2)

Tags: linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon. I am trying to install uBlock Origin addons in Firefox, but:

[image]

I have a latest version of Firefox:

[image]

Why is this happening? Please help me with this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Which other addons do you have installed? Does your Firefox send a  different version in its User-Agent string? You can check on http://ifconfig.me/.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried your advice, and the User-Agent string is: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0. Why is it that it is version 50.0 not 56.0?

Comment: I already installed Privacy Badger (this is from EFF.org). The error occurred when I am trying to install the following: uBlock Origin, Cookie AutoDelete, and Decentraleyes, and probably other addons from Mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found the solution: I renamed the `prefs.js` under the default profile in `~/.mozilla/firefox/yourdefaultprofile/` to something `prefs.jsOLD` while Firefox is closed. Then I re-opened Firefox, checked the User-Agent string using the website provided by @Wieland. The result now is: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0.

Comment: Had the same issue on Windows. The file location for prefs.json was in `C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default-*`. Be warned that renaming the prefs.js will reset all your Firefox preferences to default.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have fingerprinting disabled in Firefox Config.

Type in the addressbar
[about:config](http://about:config)
and then search for
`privacy.resistFingerprinting`
if its `true`, Firefox sends the wrong info.

Switch it to `false`and it will working again.